# Throw new exception

Tags: java

I have a problem in my code regarding throw new exception.

In one of the JTextField I enter number 0 but it is incorrect and after I click "ENTER" botton in this moment there is thrown new  exception message:

```
throw new Exception("Wrong number of express lanes range beginnig!! \n Please enter positive number!");
```

The box message appear with error message I can only click "OK". After I click "Ok" I want that the program stop because I want to correct wrong data in the JTextField. I can't do that because after I click "OK the program continues process. How can I stop the program and correct the data? 
Here is important part of the code where I see I have a problem.

```
    public class UILayer 
{

private JTextField text1, text2, text3, text4, text5, text6;

private void validateNumbers() throws Exception
{


    if(!text1.getText().equals("") && 
            Integer.parseInt(text1.getText()) <= 0 )
        throw new Exception("Wrong number of lanes!! \n Please enter positive number!");
    if(!text2.getText().equals("") && 
            Integer.parseInt(text2.getText()) <= 0 )
        throw new Exception("Wrong number of express lanes!! \n Please enter positive number!");

    if(!text3.getText().equals("") && 
            Integer.parseInt(text3.getText()) <= 0 )
        throw new Exception("Wrong number of express lanes range beginnig!! \n Please enter positive number!");

    if(!text4.getText().equals("") && 
            Integer.parseInt(text4.getText()) <= 0 )
        throw new Exception("Wrong number of express lanes range ending!! \n Please enter positive number!");
    if(!text5.getText().equals("") && 
            Integer.parseInt(text5.getText()) <= 0 )
        throw new Exception("Wrong number of customers!! \n Please enter positive number!");
    if(!text6.getText().equals("") && 
            Integer.parseInt(text6.getText()) <= 0 )
        throw new Exception("Wrong number of max items!! \n Please enter positive number!");

}

protected class EnterClickListener implements ActionListener
{
    private SimulationConfig info;

    EnterClickListener( )
    { 
        info = new SimulationConfig();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent event ) 
    {   
        try
        {
            if(!(event.getActionCommand().equals(null )))
            {
                validateForm();
                validateNumbers();
            }   
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException e) 
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "Error.\nPlease enter number.", 
                     "Message", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE );
        } 
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "Error.\n" + e.getMessage() , 
                     "Message", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE );
        }
        info.setCustomerRestriction(Integer.parseInt(text5.getText()), Integer.parseInt(text6.getText()));
        info.setExpressRange(Integer.parseInt(text3.getText()), Integer.parseInt(text4.getText()));
        info.setLanesNum(Integer.parseInt(text1.getText()), Integer.parseInt(text2.getText()));
        showProgressBar();
        task = blayer.startSimulation(info);
        task.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener());
        task.execute();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

put your code

```
info.setCustomerRestriction(Integer.parseInt(text5.getText())....
......
task.execute();
```

inside try, after if. like this:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent event ) 
{   
    try
    {
        if(!(event.getActionCommand().equals(null )))
        {
            validateForm();
            validateNumbers();

            info.setCustomerRestriction(Integer.parseInt(text5.getText()), Integer.parseInt(text6.getText()));
    info.setExpressRange(Integer.parseInt(text3.getText()), Integer.parseInt(text4.getText()));
    info.setLanesNum(Integer.parseInt(text1.getText()), Integer.parseInt(text2.getText()));
    showProgressBar();
    task = blayer.startSimulation(info);
    task.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener());
    task.execute();
        }   
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException e) 
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "Error.\nPlease enter number.", 
                 "Message", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE );
    } 
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "Error.\n" + e.getMessage() , 
                 "Message", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE );
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution provided by PC is quite better an alternate is just write a user defined Exception class that has the ability to abort the further program execution, as you can reuse it and thus no need of writing same code again(In case if you are going to handle the same Exception in multiple places or java classes).
What you need to do is:

1. Take a public class extending to RuntimeException, Exception or
   Throwable according to your requirement
2. Take a public constructor with a String parameter
3. Call to super(your_String_parameter_here); form inside of your
   constructor(So that if you are skipping to handle this Exception and
   direct handle to Super class Exception the appropriate message can
   be passed up to there)
4. override toString() method to provide proper string message for your
   Exception class object

Now you can reuse this Exception class any where in your code.